# How do cards work with family sharing beta - can I earn cards for games I don't own?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards, steam-family-sharing

Under normal circumstances, you [can't earn cards for demos or free-to-play games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125512/125519#125519) you haven't paid for, to prevent abuse.  But how does this work with the new [family sharing feature](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3784-QLBM-5731)?

If my brother plays one of my games under his account, do I get the cards, or does he?  Do the cards get counted towards my card-allotment, or his?  Or are cards simply only handed out when the owner plays?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither. From a buyers point of view, it's not fair if someone else gets the card you paid for. From a borrowers point of view, it's not really fair that someone else gets the cards with your playtime.

You said it yourself: you cannot get cards for games you haven't paid for. This holds also for games with the family sharing feature. If your brother plays a foreign-library game, which he hasn't bought yet, he will get no card drops for this game. There are [even bug reports](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/1/792923683866106743/) on this matter, since those game will show up in your badge process, with 0 card drops, but you're not eligible for a booster pack.

All in all, only those who paid for the game will get cards when they play the game.